# How to find "revision number" and appropriate Windows version to read files off an old deduped disk?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, windows-server, deduplication

I have a disk that's come off a dead server.

It's clearly deduped - the classic errors 1305, 80070519 and "bad revision" when I try to copy the files show that. I've tried every Windows Server install I can lay my hands on, to copy the files over to the new server, and cannot find one that will read it.

There's no evidence that the disk is corrupt (it was in use just last week but the server it was in, was sold), and chkdsk says no errors found. There's no reason to think the data is inherently unreadable.

I know it must have been created under NTFS using some version from 2008 - 2016, and I would expect backwards compatibility + server 2016 to handle it. But it isn't.

Is there a way to directly identify which version of Windows this needs, or what it thinks it needs, to read the files?

**Update - screenshot on my clean install:**

### [image]

Comment: NTFS is fully backwards compatible so something else is going on.

Comment: But what? I've now run chkdsk and `start-dedupjob -type scrubbing -full`, both come back no errors and I'm *still* getting the same errors on a clean install...... what else is there to check?

Comment: Screenshot added.